# SCSS appearing overflow after adding a child

Tags: html, css, overflow, parent-child

I have some issue that i cant diagnose correctly.
After adding two or more children to my #inside-content overflow appears to whole page.
Only if number of children is 1 or less the page is correct.
I dont know what i missed.

HTML:

```
<div id="page-content">
    <section id="inside-content">
      <div class="front-photo">
      </div>
      <div class="info">
          <div></div>
      </div>
      </section>
</div>
```

SCSS:

```
html,body{
  height:100vh;width:100vw;
  margin:0;padding:0;
}
#page-content{ // main container
  height:100vh;width:100vw;
  padding:0;margin:0;
  position:absolute;
}
#inside-content{
    height:100%;width:100%;
     .front-photo{
        height:100%;width:100%;
    }
    .info{
      height:200px;width:100%;
      background:blue;
      margin:0;padding:0;
      div {
        background:red;
        height:100px;width:100px;
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You set the height of class .front-foto to 100%, this is why it fills the whole screen and then of course it has to scroll.

Comment: Sorry, i meant horizontal overflow not vertical - its obvious that divs are bigger than actual screen with one element sized 100%. But i dont get it how it scrolls horizontally.

Comment: What do you need the "position: absolute" at page-content for? this is causing the issue. 

If you want to keep it you could try to add "left: 0; right: 0" to it. But I can't think of a reason why you would do that.

Comment: But it didn't change anything when i changed the position of this section. Could you explain me how it works, and how i can get rid off this weird overflow issue?

Comment: Hmm, which Browser are you using, which screen size?